# In Gmail, how do I set the default email address for a contact that has two email addresses?

Tags: gmail, gmail-contacts

When I enter the person's name in the `To` field, the auto-complete comes up, and lists the several email addresses that I have for this person.  The first email address that it lists, is not the one that I want to email.

In the contact entry for this user, I have the email address I want to use as the top one.  I believe this used to work in gmail, but doesn't anymore.

Is there a way to set the default email address for a person?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The email address in the first position of the contact's settings is used to decide which of your contact's pictures to display. He/she must have set it for public display in gmail's settings for this to work.

The email address that is shown on top for auto-complete is the most contacted address, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

I had a contact with two email addresses:

- x@gmail.com
- y@company.com

And in my prediction list, it would choose y@company.com. I was able to change the default by removing the second email address and re-adding it.

I suggest you try editing the contact on your mobile phone - long press on the email address you wish to be your default and you have the option of setting it as the default email address for your contact :-)

Answer (score -1):

I GOT IT!!  Copy the secondary email - hold it somewhere.
Delete the PRIMARY or default one.
SAVE it. You have to save it.
Then edit again, and paste the secondary one in as a new email.
It keeps the older one as primary.
Save and quit.