# In Gmail, with a contact that has multiple email addresses, how do I set the default email address?

Tags: gmail, contacts, gmail-contacts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In Gmail, how do I set the default email address for a contact that has two email addresses?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7169/in-gmail-how-do-i-set-the-default-email-address-for-a-contact-that-has-two-email)

In Gmail, with a contact that has multiple email addresses, how do I set the default email address?

The order in which they are defined does not seem to have affect.
Also the "tag" home/work/other does not seem to have affect.

Is it, perhaps, some sort of "most used at the top" kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to mark an email as a default.  I think Gmail sorts the email initially based on the Contact Name and then on the actual Email Address.

For instance for a contact name **Barry O'Connor** with one email as *barry.oconnor@sin* and the other is *barryoconnor@gm*  (I haven't put the whole email address here)

If you type **barry** in the To: box it will display both email addresses. Type an **.** or a an **o** it will filter down to one email address.

If you type the full contact name **Barry O'Connor** then you have to choose which email to use from the box.

I would have uploaded images to explain this but there seems to be a problem with Imgur.com at the moment.